# Predictive Text for VBA not working

Tags: excel, intellisense, excel-2016, vba

Okay this might be a very stupid question but my predictive text when writing only happens occasionally. I'm currently using Excel 2016.

Typing `Range(` opens the tooltip:
[image: Screenshot showing the Tooltip displaying correctly]
 
But, typing `.Range(` in `With Sheets(SName)` does **not** open the tooltip:
[image: Screenshot showing the Tooltip not displaying :(]

Can anybody help? Thank you very much!

Comment: @aaa - this is not a problem with the code, it's with [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx), so OP *has* to post a screenshot

Comment: @Chronocidal Fair enough, but I've read the things a couple of times, and I still haven't understood what's being asked. There isn't enough info here to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel can't work out what Object Type `Sheets(SName)` is, so [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) can't provide tips.

This is to be expected, since the `Sheets` collection contains both `Worksheet` *and* `Chart` Objects.  This means that it doesn't know what the Arguments for the `Range` collection should be - or even that it *is* a collection.  (Think about the `.Add` method - different arguments for every object type!)

However, a quick test shows that it *still* can't identify the Object type if you use `Worksheets(SName)` - even though all objects in the `Worksheets` collection are `Worksheet` objects.

The following code **does** allow Excel to identify the Object type, and thus allows IntelliSense to display:

```
Option Explicit 'Always put this at the top of your Module!

Sub DataRoll()
    Dim wsTMP As Worksheet, SName As String

    SName = "Testing"

    Set wsTMP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName)

    With wsTMP
        .Range 'IntelliSense will pop up as soon as you add "("
    End With

    Set wsTMP = Nothing 'Tidy up after ourselves
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I understand where the issue is. I just dont know where the problem was before this.

Answer (score 3):

Intellisense is auto enabled in VBA, not sure what you mean when you say it happens occasionally ( An example scenario when it would not appear would help us understand better)

However you can try the following steps:

1. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> within the editor (Which brings about a list of available predictions)
2. Alternatively you can Navigate to the Object Browser (<kbd>F2</kbd>) which allows you to explore the class libraries and the available objects

See below screen shot for example ( When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> after `Sheets( )`

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for the information! Will experiment with this.

Comment: As little as "Try Ctrl + Space" helped me lots, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal behaviour. I'm working with excel vba for a longer time. If you remove the bracket and rewrite it the predictive text should appear again.

But more helpful could be the Object Catalouge [image]