# MS VBA editor hides members hint

Tags: vba

I am implementing a little macros on the VBA now. The version of the Office is 2016 (16.0.5032.1000), 32-bit. And there is an annoying thing in the VBA editor: I can't use the members list because it always disappears after a couple of seconds. I.e., I type a variable's name, then a dot and its members list appears. At this stage, all is OK. But, after two or three seconds it disappears and, at the same time, VBA editor highlights the line being edited with red color. I have tried to toggle the "Auto Syntax Check", but with no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506773/predictive-text-for-vba-not-working

Comment: @braX, and?.. I'm not sure, I understood you. The question you posted is about another a bit.

Comment: You are speaking about intellisense, right?

Comment: Yes, I am. But in this two questions different aspects of the IntelliSense are being discussed.

Comment: In general, I feel like this is specific case of buggy state of the Office on mine machine. Because I didn't found someone reported about this.

Comment: Have you tried repairing/reinstalling it?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the 3rd-party program's template caused this issue. It was installed in the MS Word STARTUP directory and after its deletion the issue was gone.